# Not able to Import simplegraph from simplegraph in python

Tags: python-2.7, semantics

I want to import Simplegraph. I am getting a IMPORTERROR in python IDLE. I have attached the Error below.

```
 from simplegraph import simplegraph

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
   from simplegraph import simplegraph
ImportError: cannot import name simplegraph
```

Comment: have you installed simplegraph?

Comment: Sorry I thought It is not Case sensitive. Now it worked.

Comment: Voting to close this as it is but a typo